# Programmatically find eclipse installation directory

Tags: eclipse, plugins, path, executable

In my eclipse plugin(A), I need to programmatically get a path to eclipse.exe, which runs the plugin(A).

Does anybody know API to get this path? I am not looking for a resource in a plugin but eclipse.exe itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import org.eclipse.osgi.service.datalocation.Location;

public <T> T getService(Class<T> clazz, String filter) {
        BundleContext context = getBundle().getBundleContext();
        ServiceTracker tracker = null;
        try{ 
            tracker = new ServiceTracker(context, context.createFilter("(&(" + Constants.OBJECTCLASS + "=" + clazz.getName()  //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
                    + ")" + filter + ")"), null); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            tracker.open();
            return (T) tracker.getService();
        } catch (InvalidSyntaxException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(tracker != null)
                tracker.close();
        }
    }

getService(Location.class, Location.INSTALL_FILTER)
```

Comment: This gets you the osgi.install.area which is where the exe will be by default, but this can be different from the actual location of the launcher executable in some cases.  The executable does pass its location into java and org.eclipse.equinox.launcher sets the system property "eclipse.launcher" with this value.

Comment: Getting system property was even simpler! Great.

Answer (score 2):

This was a comment in the answer above by Andrew Niefer, much simplier:

```
String eclipseExecutablePath = System.getProperty("eclipse.launcher");
System.out.println(eclipseExecutablePath);
```

Comment: I think that this way do not work well when run eclipse from command line